# Calculate object position direction after collision

Tags: android, game-engine, surfaceview, game-physics

I am writing my own game engine (a very base one), I want to learn how physics work in game development and not using an already built game engine. I am writing my code in Java for Android devices (using SurfaceView).

The problem is that I don't know how to calculate the position for my object after a collision. I have created my own collision detection and it is working perfectly.

[image]

As you can see, the red rectangle is the area where my ball should move. The arrows is showing where the ball should move after a collision happens. The ball have different position, marked with 1 - 11 (note, while rendering the "world" you see only one ball!).

The balls are actually **rectangles**! But you can not see the edges.

I have created my own Game Object class, where I'm keeping data about the object position, velocity, origin, etc.:

```
public abstract class GameObject
{
    public Vector2 dimension;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public Vector2 origin;

    public Rectangle rectangle;

    public GameObject(Resources resources)
    {
        this.dimension = new Vector2();
        this.position = new Vector2();
        this.velocity = new Vector2();
        this.origin = new Vector2();

        this.rectangle = new Rectangle();
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime)
    {
        position.x += velocity.x;
        position.y += velocity.y;

        rectangle.set(position.x, position.y, dimension.x, dimension.y);

        origin.x = position.x + dimension.x / 2;
        origin.y = position.y + dimension.y / 2;
    }
}
```

This method is called if a ball collide with one of the red rectangle margins:

```
protected void onBallCollideWithLevelEdge(Ball ball)
{
   // Calculate next position:
   ??????????
}
```

My ball have a velocity and a position. Should I save the previous position of the ball?

Comment: I'm guessing your collision detector has determined that the ball and the wall overlap.  If you just change the velocity and not the position, you will render a frame with the ball and wall overlapping.  You need to back the object up a bit.  You can find a discussion (and a very rudimentary implementation) in https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/GameState.java#1801

Answer (score 0):

1) Why do you represents balls as rectangles? Circle is far more easy to handle, expecially if you want to extend collision to ball-ball.

2) If you are trying to make a physics engine you must have coordinates of all objects and the respective first and second derivatives, aka speed and acceleration. Moreover you need a mass for each object and maybe some other parameters, for example material (for friction) and elasticity, but this is not needed at the beginning.

3) When a collision with walls happens you have current ball position and velocity. Given this data you have to calculate normal force. Normal force is such that ball cannot pass through the wall, so I'd calculate it's magnitude using something like this:

```
Nx = DELTAx*k;
Ny = DELTAy*k;
```

where k is some elasticity constant that you can trim and x is the measure of how much the ball has penetrated in the wall. Note that this is good only for "slow" objects. If you deal with bullets you'd better using something like rays or.
Another way could be to calculate kinetic energy at the time of collision and transfer it to elastic energy. Once you have elastic energy you can release it in a direction normal to the wall, transforming it to a force. 
Once you have the force, it becomes an acceleration by dividing it for the mass.

4) at each simulation iteration you add speed to position, and acceleration to speed, remembering of multiplying it for the integration time (dt). This time can be set arbitrarly and it's a constant. If you want a 100Hz simulation you set dt to 10ms. You also have to recalculate acceleration as the sum of forces divided by the mass.

5) As you note I never talked about direction because you don't need it if you are reasoning decomposing coordinates in each axis (x,y in a 2D engine). If the normal force is "right", as in your example, the Ny component will be set to zero, while Nx will be tranformed into acceleration and will change the horizontal speed. This also will change the ball's direction.

These are only advices, actually you should start by studying kinematics and later something of rational mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

I had an function that looked something like this:

Position calculateValidPosition(Position start, Position end)
    Position middlePoint = (start + end) /2

```
if (middlePoint == start || middlePoint == end)
    return start 

if( isColliding(middlePont) )
    return calculateValidPosition(start, middlePoint)
else
    return calculate(middlePoint, end)
```

I just made this code on the fly, so there would be a lot of room for improvements... starting by not making it recursive.

This function would be called when a collision is detected, passing as a parameter the last valid position of the object, and the current invalid position. On each iteration, the first parameter is always valid (no collition), and the second one is invalid (there is collition).

But I think this can give you an idea of a possible solution, so you can adapt it to your needs.